# How to check version of Ioncube a script was encrypted with?

Tags: php, ioncube

I have a script that's encoded with Ioncube.  I've found tons of resources online about how to find the version of Ioncube that's installed on your service, but I can't seem to find anywhere that explains how to find the version that the script was encrypted with...

This is at the very beginning of the script:

```
<?php //0046a
if(!extension_loaded('ionCube Loader')){$__oc=strtolower(substr(php_uname(),0,3));$__ln='ioncube_loader_'.$__oc.'_'.substr(phpversion(),0,3).(($__oc=='win')?'.dll':'.so');if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}$__ln='/ioncube/'.$__ln;$__oid=$__id=realpath(ini_get('extension_dir'));$__here=dirname(__FILE__);if(strlen($__id)>1&&$__id[1]==':'){$__id=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__id,2));$__here=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__here,2));}$__rd=str_repeat('/..',substr_count($__id,'/')).$__here.'/';$__i=strlen($__rd);while($__i--){if($__rd[$__i]=='/'){$__lp=substr($__rd,0,$__i).$__ln;if(file_exists($__oid.$__lp)){$__ln=$__lp;break;}}}if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);}}else{die('The file '.__FILE__." is corrupted.\n");}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}echo('Site error: the file <b>'.__FILE__.'</b> requires the ionCube PHP Loader '.basename($__ln).' to be installed by the website operator. If you are the website operator please use the <a href="http://www.ioncube.com/lw/">ionCube Loader Wizard</a> to assist with installation.');exit(199);
?>
```

Can you tell what version is being used from just this?

Comment: *Can you tell what version is being used from just this?* no.

Comment: The version right before the one, and right after the other.

Comment: Is it possible that the number `0046a` on the first line is related to the version?

Comment: @duskwuff The number at the start, if present, is related to any PHP code and comments at the start of the file. It is not directly related to Encoder product version.

Comment: Hi @user557846,  have you get answer ?